# Managing libraries

Tags: package-management, libraries

After a new installation of Debian, I'm looking for a way to separate files created from new packages from my main system. I want to do this to avoid bloating the size of my drive with unnecessary libraries or packages and would prefer the files be in a different drive or folder that can be deleted or used to monitor what packages should be removed.

Specific example:
I've installed the cairo library so that I can compile a certain application. Suppose I later decide to uninstall this application. From my understanding, I think that just uninstalling the application will not remove the program entirely because the package manager will still keep the required library because I asked for it to be installed explicitly instead of automatically installed as part of a package dependency. How will I remember to remove this associated library? I want to do this for 10 applications at once.

I also sometimes manually install packages to try and fix certain problems or add features to an application but later find out that the installation was not actually what I wanted, and I can later forget that I've installed it. How can I detect that a package I manually installed is not actually being used by me?

I'm asking this because on my last installation of Debian, my root partition became a little bloated and I wasn't able to figure out why. It was about about 3 times the size of mt root partition now. This question is based on inference, and what I've read about how Debians package management works. Please correct any confusion.

Comment: I would look into the workings of `apt` before you try this.  It can easily remove libraries which you previously installed but no-longer need.  When you install a program (`apt-get install ...`) it will install extra libraries as they are needed.  When you remove the same program (`apt-get autoremove ...`) will check if the libraries are still required and remove them if not.

Comment: @PhilipCouling How will I know which manually installed packages are taking the most space or are not actually being used? And If I do know that, how can I remove all of them at once?

Comment: "manually installed packages" are no different to automatically installed packages. They're packages, and as such they're managed through the `apt` family of utilities. My approach tends to be to install a relatively minimal system and add applications only as and when I need/want them.